# How to solve expected of type 'a Conduit_async.io in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I want to get the headers of http response by cohttp

```
open Core
open Async
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_async

let cli_hdr url =
  let uri = Uri.of_string url in
  let%bind resp_head = Cohttp_async.Client.head uri in
  resp_head |> Response.headers |> Header.to_string >>| fun hdrs ->
  print_endline hdrs

let () =
  Command.async_basic
    ~summary:"Retrieve definitions from dudugo search engine"
    Command.Spec.(
      empty
      +> anon ("link" %: string)
    )
    (fun link () -> cli_hdr link)
  |> Command.run
```

But there's an type error when compiling the programming:

```
$ corebuild -pkg async,cohttp,cohttp.async test.native
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -w A-4-33-40-41-42-43-34-44 -strict-sequence -g -bin-annot -short-paths -thread -package async,cohttp,cohttp.async -package core -ppx 'ppx-jane -as-ppx' -o test.cmo test.ml
File "test.ml", line 17, characters 2-51:
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type 'a Conduit_async.io
Command exited with code 2.
```

I was wondering how to make it work?

Comment: Not sure about this, I don't know core, but looking up in RWO, Chapter 18, I found code fragments that approximately matches yours, but something is missing in your code right between `anon` and `"link"`, which is where the compiler seems to choke. Perhaps you need to look at the chapter again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `let%map` instead of `let%bind` as follows

```
let cli_hdr url =
  let uri = Uri.of_string url in
  let%map resp_head = Cohttp_async.Client.head uri in
  resp_head
  |> Response.headers
  |> Header.to_string
  |> print_endline
```